# Why doesn't aliasing constructor of std::shared_ptr initialize std::enabled_shared_from_this?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, shared-ptr

Consider the following code:

```
struct Foo : std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo>
{

};

struct Bar
{
    Foo foo;
};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<Bar> bar_p(new Bar);

    //make shared_ptr to member with aliasing constructor
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo_p(bar_p, &bar_p->foo);
    assert(bar_p->foo.shared_from_this()); //fail! throws bad_weak_ptr
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected (at least in GCC 4.8.2). I looked into code and it seems that aliasing constructor simply doesn't call `__enable_shared_from_this_helper()` which is necessary for proper work of `shared_from_this()`.

Does anybody have any idea why it was designed in such a way? Is there something wrong with returning shared_ptr to member from shared_from_this?

Answer (score 7):

[util.smartptr.shared.const]

> `template<class Y> shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y>& r, T* p) noexcept;`
>
> Effects: Constructs a `shared_ptr` instance that **stores** `p` and **shares ownership** with `r`.

`foo_p` takes no ownership of `bar_p->foo` when you call the aliasing constructor, which in this case is a *very* good thing because otherwise it would try to `delete` it on destruction.

[util.smartptr.enab]

> `shared_ptr<T> shared_from_this();`
>
> `shared_ptr<T const> shared_from_this() const;`
>
> Requires: [...]There shall be at least one `shared_ptr` instance p that owns `&t`.

As `bar_p->foo` isn't owned by at least one `shared_ptr` you end up with undefined behavior, gcc throws `bad_weak_ptr` but it isn't obliged to do anything helpful.

Comment: Ok, that's the behaviour, but what is the rationale for this? Why `shared_from_this()` doesn't require that there is at least one `shared_ptr` that *stores* `p`?

Comment: Because there's absolutely no way of keeping count of who owns a raw pointer and what it plans on doing with it, you seem to think that `shared_ptr` knows or cares about the lifetime of `p`, let alone if it's part of a hierarchy that may or may not involve another `shared_ptr` instance.

Comment: I assume, that aliasing constructor of shared_ptr is properly used only if it's lifetime of `p` is guaranteed by `r` (as in the case when `p` points to member of structure pointed by `r`). In such a case, `shared_ptr` cares about the lifetime of `p` indirectly. In other cases `shared_ptr` is invalid anyway.

Comment: I'm with peper0.  I don't see any technical reason why this can't be done.  @user657267: The aliasing constructor *does* share the control block with `r` and that is the lifetime that we care about since `p`'s lifetime is directly tied to `r`.  I think it would be helpful for p's shared_from_this to be populated to refer to the owner's lifetime.